# Create new Event_ID based on ID with sliding window on date column

Tags: sql, r, oracle, sliding-window

Imagine I have a table like

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 |
| 1 | 2021-01-17 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | 2021-02-18 |
| 1 | 2021-02-28 |
| 1 | 2021-03-30 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 2021-01-14 |
| 2 | 2021-02-15 |

I want to select all data on this table, but creating a new column with a new Event_ID. An Event is defined as all the rows with the same ID, within a time frame of 15 days. The issue is that I want the time frame to move - as in the first 3 rows: row 2 is within the 15 days of row 1 (so they belong to the same event). Row 3 is within 15 days of row 2 (but further apart from row 1), but I want it to be added to the same event as before. (Note: the table is not ordered like in the example, it was just for convenience).

The output should be

| ID | Date | Event_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-17 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-02-18 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-02-28 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-03-30 | 3 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-01-14 | 4 |
| 2 | 2021-02-15 | 5 |

I can also do it in R with data.table (depending on efficiency/performance)

Comment: `Event_ID` should be created on ordered dataframe, right? So if the data is not ordered you want to order it first before creating `Event_ID`?

Comment: No, the order of the event is irrelevant. I guess the data must be ordered somehow, in order for the correct creation of the Event_ID, but is not a prerequisite of the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one `data.table` approach in R :

```r
library(data.table)
#Change to data.table
setDT(df)
#Order the dataset
setorder(df, ID, Date)
#Set flag to TRUE/FALSE if difference is greater than 15
df[, greater_than_15 := c(TRUE, diff(Date) > 15), ID]
#Take cumulative sum to create consecutive event id.
df[, Event_ID := cumsum(greater_than_15)]
df

#    ID       Date greater_than_15 Event_ID
# 1:  1 2021-01-01            TRUE        1
# 2:  1 2021-01-05           FALSE        1
# 3:  1 2021-01-17           FALSE        1
# 4:  1 2021-02-01           FALSE        1
# 5:  1 2021-02-18            TRUE        2
# 6:  1 2021-02-28           FALSE        2
# 7:  1 2021-03-30            TRUE        3
# 8:  2 2021-01-01            TRUE        4
# 9:  2 2021-01-14           FALSE        4
#10:  2 2021-02-15            TRUE        5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
Date = structure(c(18628, 18632, 18644, 18659, 18676, 18686, 18716, 
18628, 18641, 18673), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

NEW UPDATE in Dplyr 1.1.0

With updates in `dplyr` version 1.1.0 we get two new functions/arguments.

- First is `consecutive_id()` which works exactly as `data.table::rleid()`; and
- `.by` argument in mutate which eliminates the need of `ungroup` subsequently.

Now we can now do it like this.

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                     Date = structure(c(18628, 18632, 18644, 18659, 18676, 18686, 18716, 
                                        18628, 18641, 18673), class = "Date")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)


df |>
  mutate(
    Event = c(0, diff.Date(Date)) > 15,
    .by = ID
  ) |>
  mutate(
    Event = consecutive_id(paste(ID, Event, sep = '_'))
  )
#>    ID       Date Event
#> 1   1 2021-01-01     1
#> 2   1 2021-01-05     1
#> 3   1 2021-01-17     1
#> 4   1 2021-02-01     1
#> 5   1 2021-02-18     2
#> 6   1 2021-02-28     3
#> 7   1 2021-03-30     4
#> 8   2 2021-01-01     5
#> 9   2 2021-01-14     5
#> 10  2 2021-02-15     6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

OLD ANSWER

A `r` solution may be using `dplyr` approach and `rleid` function from `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% #mutating Date column as Date
  arrange(ID, Date) %>% #arranging the rows in order
  mutate(Event = if_else(is.na(Date - lag(Date)), Date - Date, Date - lag(Date)),
         Event = paste(ID, cumsum(if_else(Event > 15, 1, 0)), sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% #since the event numbers are not to be created group-wise
  mutate(Event = rleid(Event))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     ID Date       Event
  <int> <date>     <int>
1     1 2021-01-01     1
2     1 2021-01-05     1
3     1 2021-01-17     1
4     1 2021-02-15     2
5     1 2021-02-28     2
6     1 2021-03-30     3
7     2 2021-01-01     4
8     2 2021-01-14     4
9     2 2021-02-15     5
```

Comment: Could you update your answer with the extra row I added to the question (for consistency)?

Comment: Does your answer assume that the data comes ordered? If yes, I would added the ordering step in your pipe (and for other people, I would keep the call to the library) ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! @DiogoSantos, editing it now